# Intel xeon phi programming with gcc

Tags: gcc, openmp, xeon-phi

I kind of want to get the intel xeon phi co-processor since there is a model which seems to be running for $230.  I have two questions.  Can I fully utilize the capabilities of this just using gcc along with openmp or will I need the intel compiler.  Also what is it about this model which makes it so cheap?

[http://www.amazon.com/Intel-BC31S1P-Xeon-31S1P-Coprocessor/dp/B00OMCB4JI/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1444411560&sr=8-2&keywords=intel+xeon+phi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00OMCB4JI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3100 series is a first generation of Xeon Phi (codenamed *Knights Corner*, abbreviated KNC).

1. Using GCC for Xeon Phi *KNC* programming is definitely not perfect idea. See for example: [Xeon Phi Knights Corner intrinsics with GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933394/xeon-phi-knights-corner-intrinsics-with-gcc)
2. So it's extremely recommended to use Intel Compiler for KNC. And yes, in case of non-commerical use, you can apply for free Intel Compilers license here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/qualify-for-free-software  (this is kind of new program, unavailable in past).
3. Given KNC price tag is low enough, although I periodically observe KNC sales for similar prices (so at least it's not "incomplete" Phi; and it's not cheating, although Gilles' passive cooling point is valid). I don't know which problems you work on, but you should be aware that KNC is most of all suitable for some highly parallel workloads. There is a good reference of types of applications which could benefit from using Xeon Phi KNC:  https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-xeon-phi-coprocessor-applications-and-solutions-catalog
4. As I mentioned in the beginning, you are asking about *first generation* Xeon Phi. Many things (including GCC answer) will likely change with introduction of *second generation* of Xeon Phi (codenamed Knights Landing, KNL) to be publically released in ~next year.

Answer (score 3):

Gcc permits you to compile codes and run them for Xeon Phi, and I believes it does quite a good job in that. Indeed, AFAIK, gcc is the compiler used for compiling the Linux environment available on Xeon Phi. However, for fully taking advantage of the potential performance of Xeon Phi, I would strongly encourage you to use the Intel compiler. As a matter of fact, and unless I'm greatly mistaken, you can download and install the Intel compiler suite for free for personal use.

Regarding the Xeon Phi card, it comes cheap, not really because it lacks of anything one would wand for a Xeon Phi card, but more because it is a **passively cooled card**. That means that, unless you thinker some cooling device with cardboard and fans, you won't be able to slot the card and use it in a standard PC. You'll need a rackable server which doesn't come cheap and is usually very noisy. So if you've got a server to put the card in, this is a bargain. But if you don't, you'd better think it through.

Comment: Well this one is only a bit more.  http://www.amazon.com/Intel-Xeon-5110P-1-05-Coprocessor/dp/B00FF5AP1O/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1444418024&sr=8-1&keywords=intel+xeon+phi  It has active cooling.

Comment: No, it's a passively cool card too. The picture is deceiving (probably another card) since the P in 5110P means "Passive". What you want is an "Active" card...

Comment: I don't really get why just the cooling would account for that price difference.  Also are you sure I can't use a passively cooled card.  I know there are plenty of passively cooled video cards which work just fine.  I use one to debug cuda programs.

Comment: Just browse the web, there are plenty of references to this specific issue and the ducktaping of cardboard custom air ducts... It's doable, but it's not just plug and play. Up to you.