# Vector Sum using AVX Inline Assembly on XeonPhi

Tags: c, linux, inline-assembly, xeon-phi, avx512

I am new to use XeonPhi Intel co-processor. I want to write code for a simple Vector sum using AVX 512 bit instructions. I use k1om-mpss-linux-gcc as a compiler and want to write inline assembly. Here it is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void* aligned_malloc(size_t size, size_t alignment) {

    uintptr_t r = (uintptr_t)malloc(size + --alignment + sizeof(uintptr_t));
    uintptr_t t = r + sizeof(uintptr_t);
    uintptr_t o =(t + alignment) & ~(uintptr_t)alignment;
    if (!r) return NULL;
    ((uintptr_t*)o)[-1] = r;
    return (void*)o;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Starting calculation...\n");
    int i;
    const int length = 65536;

    unsigned *A = (unsigned*) aligned_malloc(length * sizeof(unsigned), 64);
    unsigned *B = (unsigned*) aligned_malloc(length * sizeof(unsigned), 64);
    unsigned *C = (unsigned*) aligned_malloc(length * sizeof(unsigned), 64);

    for(i=0; i<length; i++){
            A[i] = 1;
            B[i] = 2;
    }

    const int AVXLength = length / 16;
    unsigned char * pA = (unsigned char *) A;
    unsigned char * pB = (unsigned char *) B;
    unsigned char * pC = (unsigned char *) C;
    for(i=0; i<AVXLength; i++ ){
            __asm__("vmovdqa32 %1,%%zmm0\n"
                    "vmovdqa32 %2,%%zmm1\n"
                    "vpaddd %0,%%zmm0,%%zmm1;"
            : "=m" (pC) : "m" (pA), "m" (pB));

            pA += 64;
            pB += 64;
            pC += 64;
    }

    // To prove that the program actually worked
    for (i=0; i <5 ; i++)
    {
            printf("C[%d] = %f\n", i, C[i]);
    }

}
```

However when I run the program, I've got segmentation fault from the asm part. Can somebody help me with that???

Thanks

Comment: KNC does not support AVX-512. You need to wait for KNL for that. You will have to look up if and how to do this with KNC using its ISA.

Comment: And try intrinsics first with the Intel compiler.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but this is not the source of my segmentation fault error. I tried 256 bit too, however I wasn't sucessful

Comment: You are not checking the  return code from `malloc()`. The GNU library already has `Function: void * aligned_alloc (size_t alignment, size_t size)` with the alignment features you need and some checking already done.  [http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html]

Comment: Did you look at the generated assembly from GCC. What is the semicolon doing in `"vpaddd %0,%%zmm0,%%zmm1;"`? I don't think you want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Knights Corner (KNC) does not have AVX512 it has something very similar. Many of the mnemonics are the same. In fact, in the OP's case the mnemoics [vmovdqa32](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4746,3030&text=vmovdqa) and [vpaddd](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4746,3030,76&text=vpadd&techs=KNC) are the same for AVX512 and KNC.

The opcodes likely differ but the compiler/assembler takes care of this. In the OPs case he/she is using a special version of GCC, `k1om-mpss-linux-gcc`  which is part of the [many core software stack](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-manycore-platform-software-stack-mpss) KNC which presumably generates the correct opcodes.  One can compile on the host using `k1om-mpss-linux-gcc` and then `scp` the binary to the KNC card. I learned about this from a comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933394/xeon-phi-knights-corner-intrinsics-with-gcc).

---

As to why the OPs code is failing I can only make guess since I don't have a KNC card to test with.

In my limited experience with GCC inline assembly I have learned that it's good to look at the generated assembly in the object file to make sure the compiler did what you expect.

When I compile your code with a normal version of GCC I see that the line `"vpaddd %0,%%zmm0,%%zmm1;"` produces assembly with the semicolon. I don't think the semicolon should be there. That could be one problem.

But since the OPs mnemonics are the same as AVX512 we can using AVX512 intrinsics to figure out the correct assembly

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
void foo(int *A, int *B, int *C) {
    __m512i a16 = _mm512_load_epi32(A);
    __m512i b16 = _mm512_load_epi32(B);
    __m512i s16 = _mm512_add_epi32(a16,b16);
    _mm512_store_epi32(C, s16);
}
```

and `gcc -mavx512f -O3 -S knc.c` procudes

```
vmovdqa64   (%rsi), %zmm0
vpaddd      (%rdi), %zmm0, %zmm0
vmovdqa64   %zmm0, (%rdx)
```

GCC chose `vmovdqa64` instead of `vmovdqa32` even though the Intel documentaion says it should be `vmovdqa32`. I am not sure why. I don't know what the difference is. I could have used the intrinsic `_mm512_load_si512` which does exist and according to Intel should map `vmovdqa32` but GCC maps it to `vmovdqa64` as well.  I am not sure why there are also  `_mm512_load_epi32` and `_mm512_load_epi64` now. SSE and AVX don't have these corresponding intrinsics.

Based on GCC's code here is the inline assembly I would use

```
__asm__ ("vmovdqa64   (%1), %%zmm0\n"
        "vpaddd      (%2), %%zmm0, %%zmm0\n"
        "vmovdqa64   %%zmm0, (%0)"
        :
        : "r" (pC), "r" (pA), "r" (pB)
        : "memory"
);
```

Maybe `vmovdqa32` should be used instead of `vmovdqa64` but I expect it does not matter.

I used the register modifier `r` instead of the memory modifier `m` because from past experience `m` the memory modifier did not produce the assembly I expected.

---

Another possibility to consider is to use a version of GCC that supports AVX512 intrinsics to generate the assembly and then use the special KNC version of GCC to convert the assembly to binary.  For example

```
gcc-5.1 -O3 -S foo.c
k1om-mpss-linux-gcc foo.s
```

This may be asking for trouble since `k1om-mpss-linux-gcc` is likely an older version of GCC. I have never done something like this before but it may work.

---

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787268/how-to-implement-mm-storeu-epi64-without-aliasing-problems/24788226#24788226) the reason the AVX512 intrinsics

```
_mm512_load/store(u)_epi32
_mm512_load/store(u)_epi64
_mm512_load/store(u)_si512
```

is that the parameters have been converted to `void*`.  For example with SSE you have to cast

```
int *x;
__m128i v;
__mm_store_si128((__m128*)x,v)
```

whereas with SSE you no longer need to

```
int *x;
__m512i;
__mm512_store_epi32(x,v);
//__mm512_store_si512(x,v); //this is also fine
```

It's still not clear to me why there is `vmovdqa32` and `vmovdqa64` (GCC only seems to use `vmovdqa64` currently) but  it's probably similar to `movaps` and `movapd` in SSE which have not real difference and exists only in case they may make a difference in the future.

---

The purpose of `vmovdqa32` and `vmovdqa64` is for masking which can be doing with these intrsics

```
_mm512_mask_load/store_epi32
_mm512_mask_load/store_epi64
```

Without masks the instructions are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

Xeon Phi Knights Corner doesn't support AVX. It only supports a special set of vector extensions, called Intel Initial Many Core Instructions ([Intel IMCI](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/513446)) with a vector size of 512b. So trying to put any sort of AVX specific assembly into a KNC code will lead to crashes.

Just wait for Knights Landing. It will support AVX-512 vector extensions.

Comment: The mneomics for KNC 512-bit SIMD and AVX512 are the same in many cases. This is true in the OPs case. So the OP needs to have a compiler which generates the right opcodes assuming his/her assembly is correct.